# Javascript eval() refactor

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a function like this:

```
function x(a,b,c) {
    eval("window.document.forms['"+ a +"']."+ b +".value = '"+ c +"'");
}
```

I understand why **eval === evil** most of the time, so what's the best way to write that function without using eval? Does the below makes sense? Why?

```
function x(a,b,c) {
    window.document.forms[a].b.value = c.toString();
}
```

Comment: why `c.toString()`? what is c

Comment: `window.document.forms[a][b].value = c`??!?!!?

Comment: Why `window.document`? Just use `document`

Comment: Keep in mind that calling `toString` on `null` or `undefined` will throw. While original version wouldn't.

Comment: @user1533609 because on the `eval` we can see the single `'` around the `c` variable I assumed it is converted to a string. Note I found this function on old code I'm working with.

Comment: @Oriol makes sense to just use `document` but is this acceptable cross-browser (desktop and mobile)?

Comment: Yes, you can access global properties as global variables and viceversa. But of course, don't shadow `document` with a more local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above function has no reason to be using `eval` - use bracket notation to access an objects property via a variable:

```
window.document.forms[a][b].value = c.toString();
```